# Why does my method increment seemingly automatically?

Tags: java, methods, return, increment, return-type

I have been working through 'Head First Java', and spent an inordinate amount of time on what was seemingly a fairly simple question. And yet, could not for the life of me figure out why the method *maybeNew* seemingly randomly increments. I spent a good amount of time assuming it was dead code.

Does *return 1* also operate as an index increaser in this case?

The code output is 14 1.

The question in the book was to work out what different flow control examples would output given the following code: e.g. having x < 19, and index < 1, for instance. Hence my confusion, given the code:

```
count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x);
```

Thank you for your patience.

```
public class Mix4 {
    int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        Mix4[] m4a = new Mix4[20];
        int x = 0;
        while (x < 9) {
            m4a[x] = new Mix4();
            m4a[x].counter = m4a[x].counter + 1;
            count = count + 1;
            count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x);
            x = x + 1; // 1;, 2;
        }
        System.out.println(count + " " + m4a[1].counter);
    }

    public int maybeNew(int index) { // index = 0;
        if (index < 5) {
            Mix4 m4 = new Mix4(); // m4 0 - 4; rn = 1;
            m4.counter = m4.counter + 1; // 1.
            // System.out.println(index);
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say that "the method increments". Do you mean that some *variable's value* increments, *when the method is run*? If so, *which one*, and *why do you not expect this*? "The code output is 14 1." Please explain exactly what you thought the answer should be instead, and step through your logic for this. Your code comments are not enough for me to understand how you are thinking.

Comment: Yeah not sure exactly what you mean by "the method increments" either, `maybeNew` will ALWAYS `return` 1 or 0.

Comment: `count = count + 1; count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x);` these two lines will always increment `count` by 1 or 2 depending on whether `maybeNew` returns 1 or 0. Is this what you have doubts about?

Comment: You specifically called out the line of code `count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x);`. Do you mean that you are confused about what happens on this line? Based on your attempt to debug the code, what do you think appears to be happening on this line? What do you think should be happening instead?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel hello, I was mostly referring to the code 'count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x);'

It does this up until Index = 4, as the parameter is Index < 5. What increases the index number? That is my confusion.

Generally, I think they have a lot of dead code to confuse me and get me to think. But I just don't get how index actually increases.

Comment: @Nexevis hello, I am referring to the parameter 'index < 5'. If you print out the parameter, you will find it goes from 0, starting point, to 4, as this is the last value allowed before 5. So, my confusion is, how does the parameter increment such that it goes 1,2,3,4,5. I don't see an index++ anywhere. I don't understand how it's incrementing. You'll notice that if you pay attention to 'count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x);', then this keeps providing + 1 to the counter, as you pointed out, obviously, as it returns 1, until, the limiter is reached: index < 5. So, what is incrementing index?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca hello, thank you for your comment.

Not quite, I understand that. But this part: .maybeNew(x), will only increment while maybeNew()'s index is < 5, thus, my main question is what is incrementing index. As partway through the program, maybeNew(x) stops outputting, no doubt because index < 5 stops being true.

Comment: @NicholasReid `index` is the parameter that's being passed to the method, i.e. `x` in your `main`, which is being incremented at the end of the loop with `x = x + 1;`

Comment: If you have `x = x + y`, and you know that `y` is either equal to `0` or to `1`, does it surprise you when you discover that `x` either does not increase or increases by 1?

Comment: ".maybeNew(x), will only increment while maybeNew()'s index is < 5" You seem to be under the impression that there is a variable `index` that is associated with the `maybeNew` method, and will *maintain its value* between calls? No. The value of `index` is *set every time you call* the function, because it says `public int maybeNew(int index)`. This is a *parameter* to the function, which has its value set to the *argument* that is passed.l

Comment: Okay, refer back to the previous page. See the example with the `XCopy` class? When you try that code, the result is `42 84`, yes? Are you *surprised* by this result?

Comment: If Java is the *first* programming language you are trying to learn, then Head First Java is not the book you should use. It *explicitly tells you so* in the introduction section.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel ahhh, right my apologies brain dead moment.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the value of x, i.e., var in main, is setting the value of the parameter 'int index' in maybeNew()? I.e., **...m4a[x].maybeNew(x);**, where the x is being passed into **maybeNew(int index)**?

Thanks.

Comment: Yep, you got it.

Comment: Much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If that may help:

```
public int maybeNew(int index) { // index = 0;
    if (index < 5) {
        Mix4 m4 = new Mix4(); // m4 0 - 4; rn = 1;
        m4.counter = m4.counter + 1; // 1.
        // System.out.println(index);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The whole `new Mix4()` is useless here: that's a dead variable because you don't really do anything with `m4`.

So `maybeNew` can be written as:

```
public int maybeNew(int index) { // index = 0;
    if (index < 5) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The whole maybeNew method could also be `static` (independent of any instance of `Mix4`):

```
    int count = 0;
    Mix4[] m4a = new Mix4[20];
    int x = 0;
    while (x < 9) {
        m4a[x] = new Mix4();
        m4a[x].counter = m4a[x].counter + 1;
        count = count + 1;
        count = count + Mix4.maybeNew(x);
        x = x + 1; // 1;, 2;
    }
    System.out.println(count + " " + m4a[1].counter);
```

Since the code only ever use m4a[1], the other index are not used; you can move the `new Mix4` and further: simplify the loop:

```
    int count = 0;
    Mix4[] m4a = new Mix4[20];
    m4a[1] = new Mix4();
    m4a[1].counter = m4a[1].counter + 1;
    int x = 0;
    while (x < 9) {
        count = count + 1 + Mix4.maybeNew(x);
        x = x + 1; // 1;, 2;
    }
    System.out.println(count + " " + m4a[1].counter);
```

And finally, remove the array:

```
    int count = 0;
    Mix4 m4a = new Mix4();
    m4a.counter = m4a.counter + 1;
    int x = 0;
    while (x < 9) {
        count = count + 1 + Mix4.maybeNew(x);
        x = x + 1; // 1;, 2;
    }
    System.out.println(count + " " + m4a.counter);
```

The loop can then be read:

- add one to `count` 9 times
- add result of maybeNew(x):

  - maybeNew(0) : 1
  - maybeNew(1) : 1
  - maybeNew(2) : 1
  - maybeNew(3) : 1
  - maybeNew(4) : 1
  - maybeNew(5) : 0
  - maybeNew(6) : 0
  - maybeNew(7) : 0
  - maybeNew(8) : 0
  - add 5 to `count`

= count = 14.